# Duvidas sobre Models relacionais no Django

Tags: django

Olá,

Estou criando um sistema de Blog com o Django, nele eu tenho vários Models: Profile(que recebe um auth.User), Post(que tem um field author que recebe um Profile).
Estou desenvolvendo uma pagina para realizar a atualização de um Post, eu sei que a função user.is_authenticated verifica se o usuário está conectado, em meu caso como faço para saber se o usuário que está conectado é o mesmo do Post

Segue o código que está no meu template:

```
{% user.is_authenticated and user.id == post.user %}
   ......
{%endif%}
```

No caso ele me retornaria um object Profile e nao User, como faço para saber o User do profile, seria correto usar post.user.profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Vai depender de como estão estruturadas as relações entre os seus models, para comparar se o usuário é o mesmo que realizou a publicação você precisa comparar o usuário do request com o vinculado com o do post.

Pela sua descrição me parece que o caminho seria post > author > user, pois pela descrição "o post tem um campo author que tem vinculo com o auth.User" então ficaria assim:

```
{% user.is_authenticated and user == post.author.user %}
   ...
{%endif%}
```